# json serialization with a variable field as a string

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I have a pojo that I am unmarshalling a REST response to. One of the fields ("variable value") is just a Json variable element (can be any form). 
Is there a way to tell it to treat the field as a plain string for all cases instead of trying to deserialize to an object?

Here's a json obiect ("variable value" can be any form):

```
{"id":1, "variable value": {"name":"one", "age": 22, "data":{"key":"value"}}}
```

I would like to save this json as a class object using gson

```
public class SomeCommand {
    private Long id;
    private String data;
}
```

Comment: Why plain string instead of a `Map`?

Comment: Because I write this field to the database as String

Comment: Using what database and what mapping layer? You said Gson, which I'm not especially familiar with, but I know that you can put a `JsonNode` directly into a Postgres JSON column and retain the useful JSON query and indexing features.

Comment: I use postgre with hibernate and there is a problem with mapping json field to string in entity (json can be any form), there is an additional library that performs such serialization but i can't use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds that you would like to parse the given JSON string to transform **variable value** into `String` object. You can achieve this by creating 2 classes - `SomeCommandOriginal` and `SomeCommand` as follows:

First, convert the JSON string to `SomeCommandOriginal` to map the value of **variable value** to `JsonNode`.

```
class SomeCommandOriginal {
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("variable value")
    private JsonNode variableValue;

    //general getters and setters
}

class SomeCommand {
    private Long id;
    private String data;

    public SomeCommand(SomeCommandOriginal someCommandOriginal) {
        super();
        this.id = someCommandOriginal.id;
        this.data = someCommandOriginal.variableValue.toString();
    }

    //general getters and setters
}
```

Second, initialize an instance of `SomeCommand` and pass `someCommandOriginal` as the argument of customized constructor:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SomeCommandOriginal someCommandOriginal = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, SomeCommandOriginal.class);
SomeCommand someCommand = new SomeCommand(someCommandOriginal);
System.out.println(someCommand.getData());
```

Console output:

> {"name":"one", "age": 22, "data":{"key":"value"}}

**UPDATED**

If you are using `Gson`, just modify the datatype of variableValue to be `JsonObject` and switch to `@SerializedName` annotation as follows:

```
class SomeCommandOriginal {
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("variable value")
    private JsonObject variableValue;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

And then you can get the same result as well:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SomeCommandOriginal someCommandOriginal = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, SomeCommandOriginal.class);
SomeCommand someCommand = new SomeCommand(someCommandOriginal);
System.out.println(someCommand.getData());
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works great with jackson but how to solve this problem with the gson library?

Comment: thank you. This solution works great with gson!. I try it before, but I did the test in spring boot controller and I haven't changed the default serializator to gson, after added to spring (spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson) this solutions work great!